# Problem generating a table - Angular 12 - even without css the collor and shapes are being applied here

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am trying to create a table here with this code, and i am not understanding what is happening here.

Even if i delete all my css file, this keep rendering

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13B-q5axUcFkJAa90_6TZaAU28kOHew9w/view?usp=sharing

What am I doing wrong in here? the table should be start without any color and, look at this rounded corners at the upper side!

Thank you

this is my css

```
    .card {
    height: 60vh;
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
}

.center {

    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;

}

.center img {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin: 20px 0px;
}

h4, h6 {
    font-weight: 500;
}



.card-table
 {



   border-collapse: separate !important;
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   min-width: none;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   background-color: #fff;
   background-clip: border-box;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   border-radius: .25rem;

 }

 .center .btn {
   font-size: 14px !important;
   margin-top: 20px !important;
   font-weight: 400;
   padding: 12px 72px;
   border-radius: 3px !important;
 }
```

this is my html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="true">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card-table">
      <div class="cart-product">
        <table class="table table-responsive">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>sr num</th>
              <th>Product name</th>
              <th>Product image</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Total</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>trips</td>
              <td>Some image</td>
              <td>This is your trip details</td>
              <td>5000</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>5000</td>
              <td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger"><mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon">delete</mat-icon></button>
              </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>




<ng-container *ngIf="false" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
          <h5 class="card-title">My cart</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
          <img src="../../../assets/cart.png" alt="" />
          <h4>Your cart is empty</h4>
          <h6>Add item to it now</h6>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Shop Now</button>
        </div>
      </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Please update your question again, I think you mistakenly copy the component.html code instead of css code

Comment: Updated! sorry mate

Answer (score 0):

I run your code, online It's look like this

[image]

In CSS the `background-color`, `border-radius` are set for table style, if you don't want these style just remove it